# Brezis' exercise 8.28.11: how to prove $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left | \frac{1}{2} \alpha_k (f) - a \right |^2 < + \infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $I$ be the open interval $(0, 1)$ and $H := L^2 (I)$ equipped with the usual inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$. Consider the linear map $T: H \to H$ defined by
$$
(Tf) (x) = \int_0^x t f(t) dt + x \int_x^1 f(t)dt,
\quad x \in I.
$$

I am trying to solve a problem in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*

> **Exercise 8.28**
>
> 1. Check that $T$ is a bounded linear operator.
> 2. Check that $T$ is a compact operator.
> 3. Check that $T$ is self-adjoint.
> 4. Show that $\langle Tf, f \rangle \ge 0$ for all $f \in H$, and that $\langle Tf, f \rangle = 0$ implies $f =0$.
> 5. Set $u=T f$. Prove that $u \in H^2(I)$ and compute $u''$. Check that $u(0)=u'(1)=0$
> 6. Determine the spectrum and the eigenvalues of $T$. Examine carefully the case $\lambda=0$.
>
> In what follows, set
> $$
> e_k(x) = \sqrt{2} \sin \left[\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right) \pi x\right],
> \quad k=0,1,2, \ldots
> $$
> Given $f \in H$ we denote by $\left(\alpha_k(f)\right)$ the components of $f$ in the basis $\left(e_k\right)$.
>
> 7. Check that $\left(e_k\right)$ is an orthonormal basis of $H$.
> 8. Deduce that the sequence $\left(\tilde{e}_k\right)$ defined by
>    $$
>    \tilde{e}_k(x)=\sqrt{2} \cos \left[\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right) \pi x\right],
>    \quad k=0,1,2, \ldots,
>    $$
>    is also an orthonormal basis of $H$.
> 9. Compute $\alpha_k(f)$ for the following functions:
>    (a) $f_1(x)=\chi_{[a, b]}(x)= \begin{cases}1 & \text { if } x \in[a, b] \\ 0 & \text { if } x \notin[a, b]\end{cases}$ where $0 \leq a<b \leq 1$.
>    (b) $f_2(x)=x$.
>    (c) $f_3(x)=x^2$.
>
> Finally, we propose to characterize the functions $f \in L^2 (I)$ that belong to $H^1 (I)$, using their components $\alpha_k(f)$.
>
> 10. Assume $f \in H^1 (I)$. Prove that there exists a constant $a \in \mathbb{R}$ (depending on $f)$ such that $(k \alpha_k(f)+a)_k \in \ell^2$, i.e.,
>     $$
>     (1) \quad 
>     \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} |k \alpha_k(f)+a|^2<\infty.
>     $$
> 11. Conversely, assume that $f \in L^2 (I)$ and that $(1)$ holds for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f \in H^1 (I)$.

In my below attempt of (11.), I am stuck at proving $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left | \frac{1}{2} \alpha_k (f) - a \right |^2 < + \infty$. Could you provide some *hints* to finish the proof?

---

Fix $\varphi \in C^\infty_c (I)$. We have
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_I f \varphi' &= \int_I \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \alpha_k (f) e_k \varphi' \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \alpha_k (f) \int_I e_k \varphi' \\
&= - \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \alpha_k (f) \int_I e_k' \varphi \\
&= - \pi \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right) \alpha_k (f) \int_I \tilde e_k \varphi \\
&= - \int_I \left ( \pi \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right) \alpha_k (f)  \tilde e_k \right ) \varphi.
\end{align*}
$$

It suffices to prove
$$
v := \pi \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right) \alpha_k (f)  \tilde e_k \in L^2 (I).
$$

It remains to prove
$$
C := \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left | \left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right) \alpha_k (f) \right |^2 < + \infty.
$$

Indeed,
$$
\begin{align*}
C &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left | \left ( k \alpha_k (f) +a \right ) + \left ( \frac{1}{2} \alpha_k (f) - a \right ) \right |^2 \\
&\le \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} | k \alpha_k (f) +a |^2 + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left | \frac{1}{2} \alpha_k (f) - a \right |^2.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: did you use the fact $f\in L^2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g := f + \frac{a \pi}{\sqrt 2}$. It suffices to prove that $g \in H^1 (I)$. We have
$$
\begin{align*}
\alpha_k (g) &= \int_I e_k g \\
&= \int_I e_k \left ( f + \frac{a \pi}{\sqrt 2} \right ) \\
&= \alpha_k (f) + \frac{a \pi}{\sqrt 2} \int_I e_k \\
&= \alpha_k (f) + \frac{2 a}{2k+1},
\end{align*}
$$
which implies
$$
\begin{align*}
k \alpha_k (f) + a &= k \alpha_k (g) - \frac{2 k a}{2k+1} + a \\
&= k \alpha_k (g) + \frac{a}{2k+1}.
\end{align*}
$$

Notice that the sequence $k \mapsto \frac{a}{2k+1}$ belongs to $\ell^2$, so the sequence $k \mapsto k \alpha_k (g)$ is also in $\ell^2$. For $\varphi \in C^\infty_c (I)$, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_I g \varphi' &= \int_I \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \alpha_k (g) e_k \varphi' \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \alpha_k (g) \int_I e_k \varphi' \\
&= - \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \alpha_k (g) \int_I e_k' \varphi \\
&= - \pi \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right) \alpha_k (g) \int_I \tilde e_k \varphi \\
&= - \int_I \left ( \pi \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right) \alpha_k (g)  \tilde e_k \right ) \varphi.
\end{align*}
$$

It suffices to prove $v := \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right) \alpha_k (f)  \tilde e_k \in L^2 (I)$. By (8.), it suffices to prove $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left | \left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right) \alpha_k (g) \right |^2 < + \infty$. It follows from $f \in L^2 (I)$ that $g \in L^2 (I)$ and thus $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left | \frac{1}{2} \alpha_k (g) \right |^2 < + \infty$. It remains to prove $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left | k \alpha_k (g) \right |^2 < + \infty$, which is true.